# I want to add a custom email variable to Shopify Order Notification

Tags: shopify

Could anyone tell me how to add a custom email variable to a shopify order notification?

For example, by default the order notification already contains the following:

```
  Shipping address
    {{ shipping_address.name }}
    {{ shipping_address.street }}
    {{ shipping_address.city }}, {{ shipping_address.province }}  {{ shipping_address.zip }}
    {{ shipping_address.country }}{% endif %}
```

These variables then translate into the actual shipping address of the customer in particular.
Now I want to add a line of information from a third party source into this order notification, how would I go about this?
I need a license key put in the Shopify order notification e-mail but this license key comes from a service outside of Shopify, is there any way I could make this happen one way or another?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy if you connect an App to your shop. You could then use the App to listen for orders via a Shopify Webhook. When you accept an order you can then trigger the code to generate or get a license key, and then just send an email to the customer with the license key and any other info you need to provide. This is a simple pattern to create.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not possible for Shopify to fetch the data from your external service while it puts together the email to send to the buyer, but you can use an [orders/paid webhook](http://api.shopify.com/webhook.html) to send the license key separately from your own server.

Edward, Shopify Developer Advocate